# Converting HTML to PDFmake syntax

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf-generation, pdfmake

Is there a way to convert a valid HTML document to [PDFmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/) syntax? I have done all the designing in HTML and CSS. Is there a way to convert that into a valid PDFmake syntax?

Answer (score 2):

I had good results using [html-to-pdfmake](https://github.com/Aymkdn/html-to-pdfmake). You can check the [demo link](https://aymkdn.github.io/html-to-pdfmake/index.html) to see if your HTML is compatible but you'll still have to convert your CSS manually though.

Comment: Unfortunately, html-to-pdfmake relies on the browser's rendering.

Comment: Fortunately, it works well with jsDOM, so to convert on NodeJS server, use:

```
import htmlToPdfmake from 'html-to-pdfmake';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const pdfmakeJson = htmlToPdfmake(htmlAsString, new JSDOM());
```

Comment: Somehow, `html-topdfmake` ignores bootstrap classes. Only properties specified in `style` attribute are getting applied.

Comment: of course it requires css, margin as per pdfmake way, I provided that & it worked :)
thanks, made my day